# Как объединить пересекающиеся списки в списке списков?

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, список

У меня есть двумерный массив `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]` (подмассивы отсортированы).

Нужно отсортировать его следующим образом: если в одном подмассиве есть часть другого, то они должны слиться в один массив, так чтобы не было повторяющихся элементов. Например: `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]` должен слиться в массив `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]`. Если пересекающихся элементов нет, как в массиве `[[1, 2, 3],[5 ,6, 7]]`, то делать ничего не нужно.

Сложность ещё в том, что нужно использовать только ванильный python, **без встроенных библиотек**.

Comment: Что значит есть часть другого? Хотя бы 1 элемент? А если нет части другого, то что надо делать? Подмассивы отсортированы? Кнопка править под вопросом

Comment: Да, хотя бы один элемент, в противном случая делать ничего не надо. Подмассивы отсортированы.

Comment: А что делать, если пересечение одного подмассива может быть сразу с несколькими? Вот в примере второй и третий подмассив являются продолжением первого. Каково должно быть поведение в этом случае?

Comment: Что вы ожидаете получить на выходе для `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]` ?

Comment: @MaxU, в этом случае я хочу получить [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

Comment: По сути, нужно собрать все массивы с пересечением и прогнать через множество.

Comment: @cauf,я пытался, но не совсем понял, как это реализовать.

Comment: @MaxU Ты же понимаешь, что написал одно и то же дважды?

Comment: @MaxU, да нужно оставить все уникальные элементы. Я опечатался и добавил лишнюю 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вопользоваться рекурсией:

```
def fun(mat, ii=0):
    if ii >= len(mat) - 1:
        return mat
    for i in range(ii+1, len(mat)):
        if set(mat[i]) & set(mat[ii]):
            mat[ii] = sorted(list(set(mat.pop(i)) | set(mat[ii])))
            return fun(mat, ii)
    return fun(mat, ii+1)
```

---

тесты:

```
In [176]: fun([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
Out[176]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

In [177]: fun([[1,2,3], [4,5], [7,8], [5,6,9], [9,10]])
Out[177]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 9, 10], [7, 8]]

In [178]: fun([[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]])
Out[178]: [[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Факт пересечения отсортированных списков можно найти, используя алгоритм, похожий на процедуру Merge в MergeSort:

```
while ia < len(A) and ib < len(B):
   if A[ia] < B[ib]:
       ia += 1
   elif A[ia] > B[ib]:
       ib += 1
   else:
       нашли совпадение, слить списки
```

Объединение списков с удалением дубликатов (из вопроса не ясно, нужно ли оно), можно сделать таким же образом.